# No puedo hacer que en cada repetición de un ciclo while se cambie la suma y por ende el resultado, y así no hacer siempre la misma operación

Tags: javascript, bucles, while, random

En este código se requiere que en cada repetición se cambie la suma y por ende el resultado, y así no hacer siempre la misma operación.

De momento el código quedó como está pero el problema que es que no se puede hacer que cambie el resultado por cada repetición, es decir: o es la misma suma siempre o se cambia la suma (declarando las variables random de vuelta dentro del while) el resultado que se tiene que poner para pasar es siempre el primero que aparece, repetitivamente siempre el mismo.

```
let randomone = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
let randomtwo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
let captcha = parseInt ( prompt ("Cuanto es" + " " + randomone + " " + "+" + " " + randomtwo));

while ( captcha != (randomone + " " + randomtwo) ){
  alert("respuesta incorrecta")
  captcha = parseInt ( prompt ("Cuanto es" + " " + randomone + " " + "+" + " " + randomtwo));
}
```

Comment: \`comillas\`  con una \ antes del símbolo salen, @Sancaf, tienes que "escaparlas". Por cierto, eso de las comillas se llama `string template`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes que nada te sugiero usar camelCase para declarar tanto las variables como las funciones. Por otro lado, para tener un código más limpio podrías hacer uso de las template literals, lo cual te permite incluir variables dentro del string. Y con respecto a tu problema en particular: estás inicializando las variables fuera del loop, por ende ese método random() se aplica una sola vez. Cuando llamas las variables estás llamando el valor resultante y no la función que lo produjo.
Tené en cuenta además que en la comparación que haces en tu while no estás comparando el captcha con la suma de ambos números, sino con un string (chequealo haciendo un console.log). Cambiando esas cositas y reasignando un valor a las variables dentro del loop, tu código quedaría así:

```
let randomOne = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
let randomTwo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
let captcha = parseInt(prompt(`Cuánto es ${randomOne} + ${randomTwo}`))

while (captcha != randomOne + randomTwo) {
    alert('respuesta incorrecta')
    randomOne = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
    randomTwo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
    captcha = parseInt(prompt(`Cuánto es ${randomOne} + ${randomTwo}`))
}

alert('respuesta correcta!')
```

Comment: Agradezco la respuesta @Sancaf pero se te olvidó en la misma declarar al principio del código la variable randomOne pues sino, no funciona y salta el debido error por consola. De todas maneras la idea es hacerlo con un while y el código se repita si la respuesta es incorrecta y si es correcta, deje de hacerlo y salte el mensaje de que la respuesta ha sido correcta.